# HttpClient - write from one InputStream to multiple POST requests

Tags: java, http, tomcat, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have a cluster of servers (potentially remote from each other) which all run `Tomcat` and communicate over HTTP using Apache `HttpClient`.  A large number of these servers are data stores, and one of the servers is a front-facing webserver that serves as an intermediary between the client and the stores.  A user should be able to upload a file to the webserver and the webserver will pass that file to a given number of stores.

So, the question: is it possible to take the file part of the upload from the client as an `InputStream` and write to multiple `POST` requests to the stores at the same time? If I were simply writing to local files, the obvious solution would simply be to read chunks of the `InputStream` into a `byte` array buffer and write from the buffer to each of the outputs in turn, but I'm at a loss as to how to convince HttpClient to "share" a stream like this.

And yes, I *could* simply read the entire `InputStream` into an object on the webserver and write it out to each store sequentially, but since I could potentially be accepting very large files I'd have to write the data to disk and then read it back for each store server, and the number of disk operations could swiftly become prohibitive.  This is an implementation I'd prefer to avoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the stores do not have the network bandwidth to keep up, how would it "share" the stream?

You can split up the incoming file and pass it on to the stores without writing it to disk, but if just one of the stores cannot keep up, you'll have to keep that file data in memory until it can accept it. If it's a big file, or many users, it can potentially take all your memory.

More technically what I mean is that you can create 5 threads that will send data as fast as they can to the stores and keep the file data in a shared FIFO structure. When the last thread has accessed a portion and sent that portion, that data can be removed from the data structure, but not before. If one is slow, the data structure can grow huge.

The data has to be somewhere, if not memory and not hard drive, then where?

So, keep the incoming data in memory until (if?) you're running out of memory (never?), then flush it to the hard drive. Keep trying to empty the data structure with the data by getting it sent to the stores and then removing.

You can rather easily code an ExecutorService to handle the re-transmit of data and cleaning up the data structure, but it won't solve the problem magically. :)

I haven't provided source code, because you don't seem to want this solution. You might need help implementing it later if you accept that you can't magically pass the data on without there being some chance of having to buffer it on the hard drive (or a worse solution would be to throtte the user uploads to MinimumBandwidth(store1, store2, store3, store4, store5)).

**Edit/changing:**

I'm not sure you really want an ExecutorService even though I said that. I would create my own custom Thread's to handle this actually. I would create a Collection from the concurrent package, probably a LinkedBlockingQueue that holds byte arrays (not bytes, arrays of bytes). Then I would create a map from Thread->Integer that holds the current index for each thread's process in passing on the data. When all progress numbers are above say 10 (meaning all threads have sent the first 10 chunks), then I remove the first 10 byte arrays, and subtract 10 from all the thread's progress to reset it.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't even considered the issue of bandwidth variance. I guess the solution I want to avoid *is* the solution. Sorry if I sound like a putz, I'm super new to network programming and I'm kind of writing this by the seat of my pants. Is there any decent literature on `ExecutorService` I should look at?

Comment: I edited my answer to include a comment to you. The comment area was too short.

Comment: I wound up using an `ExecutorService` so I could get return values from `Callable`, but your advice was very useful and I got it doing what I needed it to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create your own output stream. Attach as many HTTP POST Clients to this stream. If you receive Date to your output stream send it to each of the connected POST Clients.